# команда hug discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

при вводе команды hug приходит ошибка

> discord.ext.commands.errors.commandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 bad Request (error code:50035): Invalid Form Body In embed.image.url: Scheme "h" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').

хотел что бы гифки при вводе команды отправлялись в чат в рандомном порядке, но не смог найти решение. пожалуйста помогите, заранее благодарен.

код:

```
HUG = ["https://tenor.com/view/hug-friends-friends-forever-anime-cartoon-gif-4874598",
    "https://tenor.com/view/mochi-peachcat-mochi-peachcat-hug-pat-gif-19092449",
    "https://tenor.com/view/cuddle-hug-anime-bunny-costumes-happy-gif-17956092",
    "https://tenor.com/view/anime-hug-sweet-love-gif-14246498"]

@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    embed = discord.Embed(title="объятия!", description="**{1}** обнял **{0}**!".format(member.name, ctx.message.author.name), color = discord.Color.purple())

    embed.set_image(url = random.choice('HUG'))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве аргумента вы передаётся строку, а не переменную

```
HUG = ["https://tenor.com/view/hug-friends-friends-forever-anime-cartoon-gif-4874598",
    "https://tenor.com/view/mochi-peachcat-mochi-peachcat-hug-pat-gif-19092449",
    "https://tenor.com/view/cuddle-hug-anime-bunny-costumes-happy-gif-17956092",
    "https://tenor.com/view/anime-hug-sweet-love-gif-14246498"]

@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    embed = discord.Embed(title="объятия!", description="**{1}** обнял **{0}**!".format(member.name, ctx.message.author.name), color = discord.Color.purple())

    embed.set_image(url = random.choice(HUG))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```